# C# - Values are overwritten in for loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to integrate LinkedIn in my app,values are overwritten in Response table

I've 3 tables

Customer Table(who posts in LinkedIn their details will be stored in this table)

```
Customer_Id   Name    Cust_date   User_id   Community

Efthok        xxxx    04-Mar-13   Efthok    LinkedIn
df343n        yyyy    27-Jun-13   df343n    LinkedIn
4retee        zzzz    01-Jul-13   4retee    LinkedIn
```

Post Table(posts will be stored here)Customer_Id is the foreign key of Customer table

```
Customer_Id   Post_Id   Posts                   PostDate      Community

Efthok        guujjk    intersted in car loan   04-Mar-2013   LinkedIn
df343n        fdg4df    we are offering loans   27-Jun-2013   LinkedIn
4retee        hgf454    ********************    01-Jul-2013   LinkedIn
```

Response Table(who give comments for the posts)
    //Here the values are overwritten in my code
    Response_Id   Customer_Id   Post_Id  Response                ResponseDate   Community

```
767hhjj       Efthok        guujjk   let me know the interest  06-Apr-2013   Linked
gdf5654       Efthok        guujjk   let me know the interest  06-Apr-2013   Linked
```

I've written this code

For getting all comments in List<>

```
  public void commentM()
    {
        XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
        d.LoadXml(content);

        XmlNodeList comments = d.SelectNodes("//comments/comment");
        foreach (XmlNode xncomment in comments)
        {
            commentId = xncomment["id"].InnerText;
            memComments = xncomment["text"].InnerText;
            string timeStamp = xncomment["creation-timestamp"].InnerText;
            double cmtTimeStamp1 = Convert.ToDouble(timeStamp);
            DateTime comment_timestamp1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(cmtTimeStamp1 / 1000d)).ToLocalTime();
            comment_timestamp = comment_timestamp1.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");

            commentData = new CommentData { CommentId = commentId, Comments = memComments, CommentTimeStamp = comment_timestamp };
            listComment.Add(commentData);
            commentM1();
        }
    }

 public void commentM1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listCustomer.Count; i++)
        {
            var grt = listCustomer[i];
            id = grt.UserId;

            for (int k = 0; k < listPost.Count; k++)
            {
                string post_id1 = listPost[k].PostId;

                for (int j = 0; j < listComment.Count; j++)
                {
                    comId = listComment[j].CommentId;
                    comments1 = listComment[j].Comments;
                    commentTime = listComment[j].CommentTimeStamp;

                    DbConnection.Open();
                    DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + comId + "'", DbConnection);
                    OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        count = DbReader[0].ToString();
                        cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);

                        if ((cnt == 0) && (memComments != ""))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into mw_response(post_id,response,response_id, resp_date,community) values('" + post_id1 + "','" + comments1 + "','" + comId + "','" + commentTime + "','LinkedIn')", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            //update productid and customerid
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update mw_response set prod_id = (select prod_id from mw_post where post_id='" + post_id1 + "'),customer_id = (select customer_id from mw_customer where customer_id = '" + id + "') where response_id = '" + comId + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                                        }
                    }
                    DbReader.Close();
                    DbConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm collecting the data in List<> for Customer,Response and Post values then looping that values in CommentM1() method.

I want to get Response(comments for Posts) properly.

If anyone give comments for this post "we are offering loans" that Post_id and customer_id from (Post Table) should store into Response Table.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in whatever creates `listComment`, and we can't see that code...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added the listComment,Please go through it

Comment: You're calling `commentM1` (weird name, btw) *within the loop* in `commentM`... that's surely not what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks still same error

Comment: Still same error after doing what? Your whole question is still pretty unclear, to be honest. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I called that commentM1 after the foreach,still I've the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
       for (int k = 0; k < listPost.Count; k++)
        {
            string post_id1 = listPost[k].PostId;

            for (int j = 0; j < listComment.Count; j++)
            {
                comId = listComment[j].CommentId;
                comments1 = listComment[j].Comments;
                commentTime = listComment[j].CommentTimeStamp;

                DbConnection.Open();
                DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from       mw_response where response_id = '" + comId + "'", DbConnection);
                OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (DbReader.Read())
                {
                    count = DbReader[0].ToString();
                    cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);

                    if ((cnt == 0) && (memComments != ""))
                    {
                        DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into mw_response(post_id,response,response_id, resp_date,community) values('" + post_id1 + "','" + comments1 + "','" + comId + "','" + commentTime + "','LinkedIn')", DbConnection);
                        DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //update productid and customerid
                        DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update mw_response set prod_id = (select prod_id from mw_post where post_id='" + post_id1 + "'),customer_id = (select customer_id from mw_customer where customer_id = '" + id + "') where response_id = '" + comId + "'", DbConnection);
                        DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                                    }
                }
                DbReader.Close();
                DbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

There is problem with this particular for loop. If you see this loop it ends only when each of the comments are added against each of the customer. Ideally you should consider the index value of the previous for loop and pass that to filter the comment from comment list and insert it in the dB. This for loop will always add duplicate record.Please remove this for and filter comment based on previous for loop index value. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks for your effort,I tried your way of code but still it is overwritten